# Use of IF in a VB Macro function

Tags: excel, vba

I have encountered an Excel Macro (Excel VBA) code which is as shown below:

```
If(Param1<=0,ParamA,ParamB)
```

Assume that the input parameters Param1, ParamA and ParamB are already been calculated.

I need to know what exactly this code snippet do [or what kind of calculation is this?], so that I can implement the same logic in Java which I am supposed to do. Any idea on this would by highly appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you paste the entire code.

Comment: @Santosh - It's ok Santosh. I think I have cracked the nut. The mentioned code snippet is called "IF Formula" in Excel VBA. This code snippet will perform terniary operation [like the one in Java]. If the given condition is true, then the first parameter  [ParamA]will be considered, else ParamB will be considered. Anyway thanks for your time. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Here is terniary for VBA `result = IIf(Param1 <= 0, ParamA, ParamB)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this is what `?` operator of java does:

`param1<=0 ? paramA : paramB`